# How to make AppBarLayout stick to top of layout

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want the **AppBarLayout** to to stick to the top of the screen when the soft keyboard appears, but it always gets pushed offscreen.

- The activity has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` (also tried setting it to default).
- I've tried setting `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` on the AppBarLayout (and various configurations of this property).
- And I've tried wrapping the AppBarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout and setting `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`, `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.

*How can I get the desired effect?*

[image: Basic layout]

[image: Soft keyboard appears and AppBarLayout dissappears]

[image: This is what I want to happen instead––Soft keyboard appears and AppBarLayout sticks to top of screen]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_menu_highlighted_item_background_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_menu_highlighted_item_text_color"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/GlobalMenuText"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_menu_highlighted_item_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

1.First set id for your AppBarLayout  **android:id="@+id/text1"** then set you FrameLayout below AppBarlayout **android:layout_below="@+id/text1"**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added the id, added the `layout_below` rule to `FrameLayout`, and I tried with and without wrapping it in a `RelativeLayout`, but had no effect. Thanks for the suggestion though.